# Building Price Comparison Site

Tags: 7

I am trying to find a way to build simple affiliate price comparison website.

Parsing feeds with the FEEDS module is really easy and straightforward. But I have some problems regarding the duplicate products from different vendors. What I want is to manually map those duplicates into one page, so I can list all different price variations by each vendor in just one page. e.g: one nokia lumia 1020 show prices from different vendors amazon, bestbuy etc.

I couldn't find any module in drupal's site but I am quite sure I am missing some important point in here. I would be glad if you could help or guide me through.

Comment: I thinks you need something like glossary or G2 or lexicon modules. I mean this kind of functionality. Views can do this I think.

Comment: thanks for your reply @xurshid29. I think this will be a good start for me